# Tag 'windows8' deveria ser 'windows-8'

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

A pergunta [*Como desabilitar combinação de teclas no windows pelo registro*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15994/como-desabilitar-combinacao-de-teclas-no-windows-pelo-registro) me chamou atenção para a presença das tags [windows8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8) e a [windows-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7).

Pelo que ficou decidido nas discussões sobre tags, elas deveriam seguir o formato [objeto-versão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objeto-vers%c3%a3o) em vez de [objetoversão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objetovers%c3%a3o). Portanto [windows-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) está certo enquanto que [windows8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8) está errado e deve ser renomeado para [windows-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8).

No entanto não é possível editar cada pergunta diretamente por que não é permitido pelo sistema criar uma tag muito parecida a uma já existente. A única forma é editar todas as 13 perguntas com a tag removendo ela, esperar 24 horas para a tag sumir do sistema, e então editar novamente aplicando a nova tag. Existe algum mecanismo melhor (diamond powers)? Devo fazer isso?

Comment: Um moderador não teria o poder de mudar o nome da tag?

Comment: Talvez eu faça o retag correto esse dias.

Comment: Então amanhã vou editar as questões e usar aqui como memória para a lista de links (pelas 24horas). @Gabe?

Answer (score 4):

Removi a tag [windows8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8), adicionei a [windows-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) - na metade das perguntas, na outra metade tive dúvida se era ou não aplicável. Lista de perguntas que tinham a tag:

1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16207/pedir-senha-do-windows-apos-um-periodo-de-inatividade (alterado)
2. [Como desabilitar combinação de teclas no windows pelo registro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15994/como-desabilitar-combinacao-de-teclas-no-windows-pelo-registro) (alterado)
3. [Como faço um evento quando clicar em um Item?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14199/como-faco-um-evento-quando-clicar-em-um-item) **(duvida*)**
4. [Erro ao ler XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14034/erro-ao-ler-xml) **(dúvida*)**
5. [Como criar um Splash Screen em Windows Phone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13990/como-criar-um-splash-screen-em-windows-phone) **(dúvida*)**
6. [Como mudar a imagem pelo codigo behind](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13886/como-mudar-a-imagem-pelo-codigo-behind) **(dúvida*)**
7. [Ler um JSON a partir de uma URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13777/ler-um-json-a-partir-de-uma-url) **(dúvida*)**
8. [Enviar sms de um dispositivo móvel via HTML5/javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12413/enviar-sms-de-um-dispositivo-movel-via-html5-javascript) **(dúvida)**

   - Nessa pergunta o usuário pede especificamente para uma solução envolvendo "qualquer sistema operativo [móvel]". Cita como exemplo (e possui as tags) [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [ios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) e [windows-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8). Considerei que as tags específicas deveriam ser removidas, e substituídas pelas tags [cross-platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform) e [dispositivos-móveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispositivos-m%c3%b3veis). Ok?
9. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11931/eclipse-nao-reconhece-o-package-gnu-io-do-rxtx **(dúvida)**

   - Me parece que o fato do usuário estar usando Windows 8 é incidental, de modo que essa tag (ou mesmo a tag genérica [windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)) não se aplica.
10. [Git (e git bash) não funciona no Windows 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10227/git-e-git-bash-nao-funciona-no-windows-8) (alterado)
11. [É possivel realizar rolagem no git bash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6027/possivel-realizar-rolagem-no-git-bash) (alterado)
12. [Telas cortadas do Delphi em Windows 8 (intermitente)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4729/telas-cortadas-do-delphi-em-windows-8-intermitente) (alterado)
13. [Como desbloquear a porta 80 do Firewall do Windows 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3076/como-desbloquear-a-porta-80-do-firewall-do-windows-8) (alterado)
14. [Problemas com lentidão Delphi e FireDAC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/516/problemas-com-lentidao-delphi-e-firedac) (alterado)

***Dúvida:**

Qual a relação entre o Windows Phone e o Windows 8? Essas perguntas eram sobre (e tinham a tag) [windows-phone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone), mas algumas delas também mencionavam o 8. Como não estou familiarizado com essa plataforma, não sei quando a tag do SO se aplica *também*, ou quando a outra é suficiente (ou mesmo se é necessário uma tag específica tipo [windows-phone-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)). Passo a resolução desse problema à comunidade.

Comment: Esqueci de fazer. Obrigado.

Comment: Pode fazer de madrugada para não dar muito bump na home? Se bem que hoje aproveitei seus bumps para matar a tag "memory" também, hehe!

Comment: Seria bom, se possível, analisar se a *tag* merece ser colocada, parece que alguns casos, nem era para ter ela.

Comment: @bfavaretto De madrugada eu não prometo, mas posso fazer de manhã antes do movimento começar - ou de noite depois que o movimento já acabou. (conforme o tempo que levar pra tag ser deletada)

Comment: Claro @mgibsonbr, como for melhor para você. Só acho bom evitar os horários de maior movimento.

Comment: Até onde eu sei WP e W8 são coisas completamente diferentes. Pode ser que usaram isto porque falta uma *tag* WP8, já que este tem características bem diferentes das versões anteriores. Ok, no item 8. Mas se manter, `windows-rt` deveria ser usado no lugar de `windows-8`. Há casos que esta tag também poderia ser usada, mas não dá p/ afirmar sem que o usuário dê indicações claras. Item 9, concordo. `windows-phone-8` provavelmente no item 3 e 4.E deixe sem nos itens 5 e 6. Certamente no item 7.